# What is the definition of Semi positive line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am looking for the definition of semipositivity for canonical line bundle. In general for line bundles. If someone know, please let me know

Answer (score 2):

There are many definitions of `semipositivity' for a line bundle.

[Here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-56/issue-8/On-semipositive-line-bundles/10.3792/pjaa.56.393.full) you can find a good survey by Takao Fujita.